# What is the algorithm for building a slicing Tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, slice

A problem on optimization where I need to build all slicing tree for a floorplan. My main issue is that I was not instructed how such floorplan is even created in the first place.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A slicing tree is a binary tree representing the slicing floor plan.
http://dropzone.tamu.edu/~wshi/pub/floorplan2.pdf
This research paper should illustrate the concept.

Comment: https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/C.L.Mumford/lisa/Introduction.html

Demonstrate better. I understand how to build the postfix expression from a slicing tree and how to build the floor plan from a postfix..but I'm missing the piece about building the either of them from just a set of basic rectangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://cas.ee.ic.ac.uk/people/gac1/Synthesis/Lecture16.pdf

Provided all I needed to understand the problem.

From a starting set of rectangle create a random floorplan. Essentially your slice tree or the polish expression with random operators (V for vertical cut, H for horizontal cut) with your rectangles (denoted by a letter). Number of internal nodes being L-1 where L is the number of external leaves.

Let's say this polish expression: 712H3H645HVHV

To optimize the floorplan try to improve it from allowed moves:

> - Swap two adjacent operands (leaf nodes) in the Polish  expression.
> - Take a chain of consecutive operators, e.g. “HVHV”, and  complement it, e.g. “VHVH”.
> - Swap an adjacent operator and operand. (But make sure still a  skewed tree!)

To know if the solution have improved, you need to compute the area:

> - Height( XYH ) = max( Height( X ), Height( Y ) )
> - Width( XYH ) = Width( X ) + Width( Y )
> - Height( XYV ) = Height( X ) + Height( Y )
> - Width( XYV ) = max( Width( X ), Width( Y ) )